# Como validar funções o tempo todo usando PHP. Para encaminhar mensagens e notificações

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Eu gostaria de orientações de boas práticas para meu projeto, estou estruturando um servidor que ira fazer validações o tempo todo, para encaminhar notificações e também mensagens a diversos setores de uma Empresa.

Exemplos:

- Se o estoque estiver menor que 10, encaminhe uma mensagem ao setor responsável, para que eles estejam cientes.
- Um cliente tentou realizar o pagamento, mas o sistema apresentou um erro. Envie uma mensagem ao setor de Suporte para que eles já entrem em contato com o Fulano da Silva...
- Todo dia ás 20h, encaminhe uma mensagem ao dono da empresa com o relatório de Faturamento...

> Utilizo o Pushcut para as notificações e o Telegram para encaminhar
> mensagens aos setores da Empresa.

Pushcut

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    $title = "Texto dinamico ";
    $btn1 = "Botão 1";
    $btn1Url = "www.empresa.com/acao1";
    $btn2 = "Botão 2";
    $btn2Url = "www.empresa.com/acao2";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.pushcut.io/v1/notifications/Faturamento');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"text\":\"Mensal\",\"title\":\"$title\",\"input\":\"My dynamic input\",\"actions\":[{\"name\":\"$btn1\",\"url\":\"$btn1Url\"}, {\"name\":\"$btn2\",\"url\":\"$btn2Url\"}]}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Accept: */*';
    $headers[] = 'Api-Key: TOKEN';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Telegram

```
<?php  
    $boturl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot#####";
    $chat_id = "123456789";
    $c="Mensagem aqui";

    file_get_contents($boturl.'/sendmessage?chat_id='.$chat_id.'&text='.$c.'&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"Press here to open URL","url":"https://example.com"}]]}'); ?>
```

Comment: As validações que eu consigo executar é apenas quando a pagina é recarregada. Mas se eu colocar um script para ficar recarregando quando houver uma alteração a pagina vai ficar em refresh o tempo todo

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar o problema, encontrei sobre Tarefas Cron ou Cron Jobs. Então coloquei em meu servidor para executar a função a cada tanto tempo e não quando houver uma alteração no banco de dados.

> Usando o seguinte comando curl "https://dominio.com/pasta/"

Após isso, foi só validar para só enviar a mensagem quando houver alguma novidade usando

if ($valida) {
// Enviar notificação
}